# DAX Calculate not Totaling

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Can anyone help me with this formula?

Calculate formula not totaling

```
Rev SWLY2 =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Fact Table'[[Revenue Net]]] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( DateTable ),
        DateTable[WeekID] = SELECTEDVALUE ( DateTable[WeekID] ) - 52
    )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the total, `SELECTEDVALUE ( DateTable[WeekID] )` returns a blank because there are multiple weeks within the filter context.

Try using `MAX` in the case instead of `SELECTEDVALUE`.

---

**Edit:** I think this should work as you'd expect:

```
Rev SWLY2 =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Fact Table'[[Revenue Net]]] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( DateTable ),
        DateTable[WeekID] + 52 IN VALUES ( DateTable[WeekID] )
    )
)
```

Note that `VALUES` is a list when there are more than one values.

Comment: This worked, but for the total it just gave me the Max i would like them to be totaled so the % chg makes sense.

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you so much for your help!